# How to append one table to another in PostGIS

Tags: append, postgis

I have two postGIS tables with geometry polygon. I want to append one to another. What will be the query?

Comment: What do you mean by append?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, such as:

```
INSERT INTO my_append(geom, col1, col2)
SELECT geom, col1, col2
FROM my_other;
```